# Function name must be a string comparison

Tags: php

I want to print the latest records in my table **UDS**.

With the following code, i can compare the 2 latest records...
If the newest record is higher than the previous record, so i print the value with green color, else if the newest record is less than the previous record, i print it with red color...else, i print it with black color

```
$mrkfStatement = $mrkfPDO->prepare("select * from uds order by id desc limit 2  ");
$mrkfStatement->execute($params);
$pays = $mrkfStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$color = 'black';
$element = $count($pays);
if ($element > 0) { // we must have got two records back from the query
    if ($pays[$element]['price'] < $pays[$element - 1]['price'])
        $color = 'red';
    elseif ($pays[$element]['price'] > $pays[$element - 1]['price'])
        $color = 'green';
}
echo "<tr><td>
                        <span style='color: $color'>"
 . $pays[$i]['price'] .
 "</span>
                    </td>
                  </tr>";
```

But i have got this error :

> Undefined variable: count
>
> Function name must be a string  ($element = $count($pays);)

Answer (score 2):

typo at `$element = $count($pays);` which should be `$element = count($pays);`

Answer (score 0):

It should be count() not $count()

So try this:

```
$element = count($pays);
```

Comment: when modify to count($pays) .. give error /// Undefined offset: 2

Answer (score 0):

Use [rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php). to get total number of rows

```
$element = $mrkfStatement->rowCount();
if ($element > 0) {
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\curl\tests\usd.php on line 29 /// if ($pays[$element]['price'] < $pays[$element - 1]['price'])

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\curl\tests\usd.php on line 36 ///// echo "<tr><td> <span style='color: $color'>" . $pays[$element]['price'] . "</span> </td> </tr>";

Comment: use for loop to retrieve data from array

Answer (score -1):

replace `$count($pays)` with `count($pays)`